# different hash between Node.js crypto-js MD5 and Golang crypto/md5.Sum()

Tags: node.js, go, hash, md5, cryptojs

how are objects treated by crypto-js' MD5-function (https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)? I am trying to replicate the hashing behaviour in Golang using the crypto/md5 (https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/md5) package, but I can't figure out why the hashes are different for my two implementations. It must be something with how crypto-js is treating objects internally, because for pure strings I am getting the same hashes.

**Node.js example:**

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let body = {"key":"value"}
let bodyHash =  CryptoJS.MD5(body);
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash)
```

Outputs the hash: SH97IvaDEtLBu8k7GupEWw==

**Golang example:**

```
import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/base64"
)

type KeyValue struct {
    Key string  `json:"key"`
}

func main() {
    body := KeyValue{
        Key: "value",
    }
    bodyByteArray, _ := json.Marshal(body)
    bodyHash := md5.Sum(bodyByteArray)
    bodyHashBase64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bodyHash)
}
```

Outputs the hash: pzU/fN3OgI3gAydHoLe+UA==

Any help and explanations are appreciated!

Comment: Look at the actual byte inputs. JSON is not entirely deterministic. It's quite possible that the two JSON implementations produce slightly different (but equivalent) outputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using md5 on an object not a string (you are hashing different things)

```js
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let body = {"key":"value"}
let bodyHash =  CryptoJS.MD5(JSON.stringify(body)); <<<<<<<<<
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash)
```

Hash: `pzU/fN3OgI3gAydHoLe+UA==`

For golang

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type KeyValue struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
}

func main() {
    body := KeyValue{
        Key: "value",
    }
    bodyByteArray, _ := json.Marshal(body)
    fmt.Println(string(bodyByteArray))
    digest := md5.New()
    digest.Write(bodyByteArray)
    bodyHash := digest.Sum(nil)
    bodyHashBase64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bodyHash)
    fmt.Println(bodyHashBase64)
}
```

Hash: `pzU/fN3OgI3gAydHoLe+UA==`

Comment: But would it be possible to get the SH97IvaDEtLBu8k7GupEWw== hash in golang?

Comment: @JohannesKrämer: why would you want to replicate the invalid hash? `SH97IvaDEtLBu8k7GupEWw== ` is the same value you get if you pass `body`, or `1` or `{}`, it's hashing whatever default these non-strings get turned into.

Comment: I think it is not possible... First because one binary data is not processed in the same way on another language (JSON Object and struct). You must start with the same types, which is string.